# Installing Ortus Commandbox on Mac OSX Sierra, running box results in errors and exceptions

Tags: java, macos, exception, homebrew, commandbox

I tried installing Commandbox from Ortus by downloading the zip file that also contains the JRE. This landed in the Downloads folder on my Mac running OSX Sierra. I unzipped it and tried running box. It first initialized stuff, then ran fine.

The installation tip here: https://ortus.gitbooks.io/commandbox-documentation/content/setup/installation.html
suggests placing the box binary in /usr/bin. I tried but couldn't. I even tried using sudo to mv it but it said I was not permitted.

SO then I decided to use the Homebrew method of installation. I installed Homebrew. When installation was complete, I then ran "brew install commandbox". It completed ok. I then typed "which box" to see which one it would find, the one in my Downloads dir or another. It showed it was in /usr/local/bin/box. Seems to be ok.

I then ran box. It crashes and burns!

```
$ box
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at cliloader.LoaderCLIMain.execute(LoaderCLIMain.java:205)
    at cliloader.LoaderCLIMain.main(LoaderCLIMain.java:705)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/VM
    at lucee.commons.collection.Hashing.randomHashSeed(Hashing.java:263)
    at lucee.commons.collection.HashMapPro.<init>(HashMapPro.java:195)
    at lucee.commons.collection.HashMapPro.<init>(HashMapPro.java:236)
    at lucee.commons.collection.LinkedHashMapPro.<init>(LinkedHashMapPro.java:70)
    at lucee.runtime.type.StructImpl.<init>(StructImpl.java:82)
    at lucee.runtime.type.StructImpl.<init>(StructImpl.java:68)
    at lucee.runtime.type.scope.ScopeSupport.<init>(ScopeSupport.java:85)
    at lucee.runtime.type.scope.ArgumentImpl.<init>(ArgumentImpl.java:67)
    at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.<init>(PageContextImpl.java:263)
    at lucee.runtime.CFMLFactoryImpl.getPageContextImpl(CFMLFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at lucee.runtime.CFMLFactoryImpl.getLuceePageContext(CFMLFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:435)
    at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.cli(CFMLEngineImpl.java:760)
    at lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineWrapper.cli(CFMLEngineWrapper.java:267)
    at luceecli.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:223)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.VM
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at lucee.loader.classloader.LuceeClassLoader.loadClass(LuceeClassLoader.java:173)
    at lucee.loader.classloader.LuceeClassLoader.loadClass(LuceeClassLoader.java:138)
    ... 21 more
Cause:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/VM
    at lucee.commons.collection.Hashing.randomHashSeed(Hashing.java:263)
    at lucee.commons.collection.HashMapPro.<init>(HashMapPro.java:195)
    at lucee.commons.collection.HashMapPro.<init>(HashMapPro.java:236)
    at lucee.commons.collection.LinkedHashMapPro.<init>(LinkedHashMapPro.java:70)
    at lucee.runtime.type.StructImpl.<init>(StructImpl.java:82)
    at lucee.runtime.type.StructImpl.<init>(StructImpl.java:68)
    at lucee.runtime.type.scope.ScopeSupport.<init>(ScopeSupport.java:85)
    at lucee.runtime.type.scope.ArgumentImpl.<init>(ArgumentImpl.java:67)
    at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.<init>(PageContextImpl.java:263)
    at lucee.runtime.CFMLFactoryImpl.getPageContextImpl(CFMLFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at lucee.runtime.CFMLFactoryImpl.getLuceePageContext(CFMLFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:435)
    at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.cli(CFMLEngineImpl.java:760)
    at lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineWrapper.cli(CFMLEngineWrapper.java:267)
    at luceecli.CLIMain.run(CLIMain.java:223)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at cliloader.LoaderCLIMain.execute(LoaderCLIMain.java:205)
    at cliloader.LoaderCLIMain.main(LoaderCLIMain.java:705)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.VM
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at lucee.loader.classloader.LuceeClassLoader.loadClass(LuceeClassLoader.java:173)
    at lucee.loader.classloader.LuceeClassLoader.loadClass(LuceeClassLoader.java:138)
    ... 21 more
```

I have no idea what to do now to fix this.

I suspect it may have fouled up things when I ran box from the Downloads folder, not realizing it would initialize stuff. I deleted the Downloads version containing both the box binary and the JRE folder and emptied the Trash.

Any suggestions on how to get Commandbox up and running now?

Comment: I did try "brew uninstall commandbox" then "brew cleanup commandbox", then tried re-installing again. But I get the same errors when I run box.

I should add that the directions don't say where to put the JRE.

Comment: Ouch!  It sounds like your machine already has Java so I wouldn't worry about the JRE.  My best guess is that box didn't fully unpack all of the jars that it needs.  Remove the `.CommandBox` folder in your user home dir and re-run box to try unpacking again.  And also, can you confirm the version of Java on your machine?  I'm wondering if you have Java 9 installed.  CommandBox isn't certified for Java 9 yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some local testing and confirmed that you're on Java 9 which isn't supported right now by CommandBox.  The fix is easy and you can leave Java 9 installed as the main JVM for your PC.  What you need to do is take the `JRE` folder that you downloaded before, or just download a server version of Java 8 and rename the folder to `JRE`.  Then place that folder in the same directory as the `box` binary.

When CommandBox first starts, it checks to see if there is a folder called `JRE` in the same folder, and if so it uses it.  If it doesn't find the folder, then it will fall back to the general version of Java your operating system has installed.

Since Java 9 is popping up more in the wild, I'll see about getting a check for it put into CommandBox to alert people with a more useful message.  We already have a similar check in place, but it only looks for Java versions less then 7.

Comment: I've already put in a fix for the next version of CommandBox 3.9.0-rc to detect Java 9 and output a more useful message until we get proper support.  https://ortussolutions.atlassian.net/browse/COMMANDBOX-712

Comment: Thanks Brad for the investigating of this issue! I probably do have Java 9 on my Mac. I will download the JRE again. As for placement, box is in /usr/local/bin which is a directory containing only links. It doesn't seem appropriate to place the JRE there.  Is there a more suitable place to put it that won't interfere with other apps on my Mac from accessing Java 9 when they need that?  I know how to create links in the terminal for redirecting JRE to wherever I place the physical folder.

Comment: I went ahead and placed the jre folder in /usr/local/lib, then created a soft link in /usr/local/bin/jre that points to it. I launched box again and it works now! Let me know if there is a more appropriate place for the jre. Thanks for your help, Brad!